# Issues with Visual Studio 2013 Update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2013, updates

I have just installed VS 2013 Update 3 and now I get errors when opening an solution:

```
The 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.WebPublishPackage,MircosoftVisualStudio.Web.Publish' 
package did not load correctly.
```

And

The `'ScaffoldungVSPackage'` package did not load correctly.

In the activity-log is shows following errors:

```
<entry>
<record>447</record>
<time>2014/08/05 14:27:31.859</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.WebPublishPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish]</description>
<guid>{1AD387FC-B1E8-4023-91FE-F22260B661DB}</guid>
<hr>80131522</hr>
<errorinfo>Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Internal.Contracts.Publish.IVsWebJobPublishService' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Internal.Contracts, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.</errorinfo>
</entry>

<entry>
<record>450</record>
<time>2014/08/05 14:31:20.199</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>SetSite failed for package [ScaffoldingVsPackage]</description>
<guid>{FAA496BF-FB16-4671-B3D5-E4B388A18478}</guid>
<hr>80131500</hr>
<errorinfo>Cannot cast the underlying exported value of type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Templating.ScaffoldingAssemblyDirectiveProcessor (ContractName="Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.IServiceRegistrar")' to type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.IServiceRegistrar'.</errorinfo>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>451</record>
<time>2014/08/05 14:31:20.199</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>End package load [ScaffoldingVsPackage]</description>
<guid>{FAA496BF-FB16-4671-B3D5-E4B388A18478}</guid>
<hr>80131500</hr>
<errorinfo>Cannot cast the underlying exported value of type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Templating.ScaffoldingAssemblyDirectiveProcessor (ContractName="Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.IServiceRegistrar")' to type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.IServiceRegistrar'.</errorinfo>
</entry>
```

Tried So Far:
Has anyone an idea how to resolve this issue? I already tried:

- Reinstalling VS2013
- Reinstalling WindowsAzureSDK V2.4
- Disabling Extensions

Thanks.

Comment: this link has helped, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173618/the-web-publishing-extension-is-not-installed-which-is-required-to-publish/25180985#25180985

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I first tried to repair Update 3 installation for Visual Studio. I'm mentioning it because it may have helped a bit, I'm not sure.

I then opened my Azure solution. Right clicked on the cloud project and selected <kbd>Properties</kbd>. In the first tab (<kbd>Application</kbd>) there was a message that my solution was using `Microsoft Azure Tools version 2.3` and I had the option to change it to version 2.4. After I switched to newer version, I restarted Visual Studio and it didn't show me error message anymore.

One other thing I had to do is to switch the startup project to the Cloud project because after the update it somehow changed to my MVC project.

And one other thing - Windows Azure SDK v2.4 deleted all my storage tables so you'll probably have the same problem..

Comment: Sorry to hear that.. It seems to me that this is a problem with Windows Azure SDK v2.4, not with Visual Studio Update 3 so you can experiment with that..

Comment: Have you tried to update all your Azure related NuGet packages in all the projects in your solution?

Comment: I don't think that it's a problem of the Azure-update, because I have the same error message, after I installed the VS-Update 3 and not the Azure-update. Nevertheless, after I updated Azure, the problem still remains.

Answer (score 1):

For ScaffoldingVsPackage errors,

I deleted everything from GAC, which started with `Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding*`

And no more errors, now!

PS: I had done a full re-install of VS2013 with Update 3 earlier, but it didn't solved my problem, until the above cleanup from GAC!

EDIT:
As "mtman" mentioned, I did perform a manual delete from GAC folder, without using the gacutil command-line.

Comment: Specifically, delete it from %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\, gacutil cannot be used as the DLLs are dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but my error is related to scaffolding item.

I need to uninstall visual studio and went through all the related folders, registry and re-install visual studio in order to make it work!

Folders that I checked:

- %App Data%
- %Program Data%
- %Program Files%
- Windows

basically I searched anything that has "visual studio" & "scaffolding" in folders & registry, delete all and restart the PC before I install the visual studio again!

Hope that help :)

Answer (score 0):

*[Sorry I don't know how to fix issue with ScaffoldingVsPackage, but this information about the Web Publish package might help you.]*

Reinstall "Web Deploy 3.5" using the "[Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)".

NOTE: I had already installed the Web Deploy 3.5 on my machine, so I needed to uninstall it first.

Visual Studio 2013 packages can be found in the registry under the **HKEY_USERS\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\Packages** key. Searching from that location for "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.WebPublishPackage" shows that the extension is installed in the **C:\Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/Extensions/Microsoft/Web Tools/Publish** folder. These files were last touched on my machine at the exact date of the Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 installation.

I tried repairing the Azure Web Tools 2.4 update, but it does nothing to these files. (That extension is installed into a completely different folder, BTW.) So, I find it curious that the error dialog points you in the wrong direction. The Azure Tools version of publish is installed under a different package name: "Microsoft.Cct.Packages.WebPublish.WebPublishPackage".

If you suspect a bad package registration, you can update the VS registry by running the following commands at an elevated command prompt:

```
devenv /setup
devenv /updateconfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve problems with WebPublishPackage do in Developer Command Prompt for VS2013 (under Administrator):

gacutil -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Internal.Contracts.dll"

gacutil -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.dll"

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET(VS 2013) - 2.8.1 and had the same issue. It turns out that I did not fully complete the installation as it requires several pc reboots. Be sure that the 'Items to be installed' count is zero on the Installer screen.