# Total GAC refresh

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

I have assemblies of uninstalled programs persisting in GAC. Whenever I run `gacutil /u <name>` on any of it, I get the "assembly is required by one or more applications" error. From the [kb article](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/873195):

> Windows Installer is a probable source of the erroneous registry entry
>   that blocks the Global Assembly Cache tool (Gacutil.exe) from
>   uninstalling the assemblies. Gacutil.exe cannot override Windows
>   Installer reference counts. Several possible causes of conflict exist
>   between Windows Installer and Gacutil.exe. If you use Windows
>   Installer to install an assembly in the GAC, Gacutil.exe may not be
>   able to remove the assembly.

The problem is causing me (and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172955/issues-with-visual-studio-2013-update-3)) perfectly strange problems with Visual Studio.

My question:

Can I uninstall all .NET frameworks, delete all of the .NET 2 & 4 GAC and be sure I will boot up again?