# Web Publishing Extension not installed in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, one-click-web-publishing

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 trying to publish my app, but when I try to do so I get the error:

> The Web Publishing Extension is not installed which is required to publish. You can install it from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=208120

I tried repairing Visual Studio and reinstalling Azure SDK for VS 2015 but the problem persists. I wanted to try the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25190969/1335209) but I don't have a folder named `Publish` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\`

Any idea about what can be the problem? I found a lot of post in SO about this problem but can't find any solution when there isn't any folder named `Publish`. I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it by reinstalling `Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools` using Visual Studio `Extensions and Updates` menu (Tools -> Extensions and Updates...)

Comment: I did that but my **Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools**  is not Editable  i mean i can't be able to reinstall it , what can i do , am using VS 2015 too

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris I don't really know but you could try with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37830882/1335209

Comment: I can't see Tools -> Extensions and Updates in the VS 2015. Also I install Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools but it is asking the same: "You can install it from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=208120"