# Uninstall Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I think this extension is causing a problem in my Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 but I can't uninstall it.

Under Extensions, it's listed but Remove/Disable buttons are grayed out. I can't find it under Remove Programs/Features either.

How in the world can I uninstall this extension?

Answer (score 4):

Uninstall via its installer:

1. [Download the latest Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools installer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935)
2. Run the installer normally.
3. Run the installer *again* and click the uninstall button.

Comment: **Not recommended** but for Visual Studio 2015 update 3 I had to find the *WebToolsExtensionsVS14.msi* file in the "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache" folder and delete its containing folder. Next, I searched the Registry (regedit.exe) for that file and deleted the corresponding key container. Running the installer worked after that.